# when trying to connect to mysql db using ploty-dash app iam getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am trying to connect my dash app to mysql database. But it is giving me this error:

```
AttributeError: ('Invalid config key. Some settings are only available via the Dash constructor', 'MYSQL_HOST')
```

Below is the code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = dash.Dash(__name__,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '1234'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'test'
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Dash uses Flask as a wrapper.
The correct mysql config setup is

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
app.server.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.server.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.server.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '1234'
app.server.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'test'
app.server.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = 3306
mysql = MySQL(app.server)
```

I spent around 1 hour trying to figure this out.I hope this helps if anyone gets stuck.